# Android: can Proguard remove unused classes from dex?

Tags: android, proguard

I have a library `jar` that includes several `dex` files. Does `Proguard` optimize / recompile those `dex` files or it runs only on `*.class` files?

Comment: Proguard only works with class files. I'm curious how and where did you get a library that contains dex files?

Comment: That library is for ad mediation. It contains sdk's of ad networks that are used in the mediation.